# Create matrix from dataset in R

Tags: r, matrix

I want to create a matrix from my data. My data consists of two columns, date and my observations for each date. I want the matrix to have year as rows and days as columns, e.g. :

```
      17   18   19   20   ...   31
1904  x11  x12  ...
1905
1906
.
.
.
2019
```

The days in this case is for December each year. I would like missing values to equal NA.

Here's a sample of my data:

```
> head(cdata)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Datum               Snödjup
  <dttm>                <dbl>
1 1904-12-01 00:00:00    0.02
2 1904-12-02 00:00:00    0.02
3 1904-12-03 00:00:00    0.01
4 1904-12-04 00:00:00    0.01
5 1904-12-12 00:00:00    0.02
6 1904-12-13 00:00:00    0.02
```

I figured that the first thing I need to do is to split the date into year, month and day (European formatting, YYYY-MM-DD) so I did that and got rid of the date column (the one that says Datum) and also got rid of the unrelevant days, namely the ones < 17.

```
cdata %>%
  dplyr::mutate(year = lubridate::year(Datum), 
                month = lubridate::month(Datum), 
                day = lubridate::day(Datum))
select(cd, -c(Datum))

cu <- cd[which(cd$day > 16
                         & cd$day < 32
                                    & cd$month == 12),]
```

and now it looks like this:

```
> cu
# A tibble: 1,284 x 4
   Snödjup  year month   day
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1    0.01  1904    12    26
 2    0.01  1904    12    27
 3    0.01  1904    12    28
 4    0.12  1904    12    29
 5    0.12  1904    12    30
 6    0.15  1904    12    31
 7    0.07  1906    12    17
 8    0.05  1906    12    18
 9    0.05  1906    12    19
10    0.04  1906    12    20
# … with 1,274 more rows
```

Now I need to fit my data into a matrix with missing values as NA. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: and what about months? Where do you want the month information?

Comment: The month doesn't matter since all the days is from December

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cdata %>%
   mutate(year = lubridate::year(Datum), 
          day = lubridate::day(Datum)) %>%
   filter(day >= 17) %>%
   complete(day = 17:31) %>%
   select(year, day, Snödjup) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = day, values_from = Snödjup)
```

Comment: Thanks! This one kind of works, but it starts with day 1, I just want day 17 - 31 of December. It doesn't show missing values as NA, the days for the missing values are instead omitted.

Comment: @user12221453 Can you check the updated answer and see if it works.

Comment: I'm afraid not. The first year (1904) was omitted and the value of the observations seems random

Comment: Ok..In that case, please give a reproducible example using `dput` so that is is easier to help when we have your data. `dput(cdata)`.

Answer (score 1):

Base R approach, using `by`.

```
r <- `colnames<-`(do.call(rbind, by(dat, substr(dat$date, 1, 4), function(x) x[2])), 1:31)
r[,17:31]
#         17    18    19   20    21    22    23   24    25    26    27    28   29    30   31
# 1904 -0.28 -2.66 -2.44 1.32 -0.31 -1.78 -0.17 1.21  1.90 -0.43 -0.26 -1.76 0.46 -0.64 0.46
# 1905  1.44 -0.43  0.66 0.32 -0.78  1.58  0.64 0.09  0.28  0.68  0.09 -2.99 0.28 -0.37 0.19
# 1906 -0.89 -1.10  1.51 0.26  0.09 -0.12 -1.19 0.61 -0.22 -0.18  0.93  0.82 1.39 -0.48 0.65
```

---

*Toy data*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1904:1906, function(x) 
  data.frame(date=seq(ISOdate(x, 12, 1, 0), ISOdate(x, 12, 31, 0), "day" ),
             value=round(rnorm(31), 2))))
```

Comment: I tried all the code with the sample data and that worked fine, but then I tried with my own:
`> r <- (do.call(rbind, by(cdata, substr(cdata$Datum, 1, 4), function(x) x[2])), 1:31)
Error: unexpected ',' in "r <- (do.call(rbind, by(cdata, substr(cdata$Datum, 1, 4), function(x) x[2])),"`

Comment: Either `"colnames<-"(do.call(rbind, by(cdata, substr(cdata$Datum, 1, 4), function(x) x[2])), 1:31)` or `do.call(rbind, by(cdata, substr(cdata$Datum, 1, 4), function(x) x[2]))` – just count your parentheses.

Comment: Okay, this sort of works. But the row names just change between 1904 and 1905. So first row is 1904, second is 1905, third is 1904, fourth is 1905 and so on.

Comment: Please consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610